# SQL создание массивов

Tags: sql, массивы

всем привет! прошу прощения за возможно кривой вопрос

у меня есть таблица такого вида

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Two |
| 2 | Four |
| 2 | One |
| 1 | Three |

подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать select так чтобы вывод был в виде массива

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [Two, Three] |
| 2 | [Four, One] |

можно отправить, где почитать
благодарю за любую помощь

Comment: Какая у вас СУБД? Например в Oracle есть коллекции, возможно в вашей СУБД есть что то аналогичное

Comment: Приветствую, СУБД clickhouse, но если на примере Oracle - тоже приму - к своему стыду не могу загуглить корректно вопрос свой

Comment: В clickhouse есть [`groupArray()`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/grouparray/).